# chown failed: Operation not permitted (permission related)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

It is my first day at Ubuntu, so I beg your pardon if I am asking a very basic question.

I have installed Ubuntu in a VirtualBox.

I am trying to run a basic command and follow instructions from [here](https://github.com/qmfrederik/extfstools).

Even realizing that running the following command as it is not  possible and took me an hour

```
ext2rd  system.img  ./:savedir
```

So i ran it like this

```
./ext2rd  system.img  ./:savedir
```

And I got this error

```
chown failed: Operation not permitted
savedir/./xbin/taskstats
```

I realized it is a permission issue. 
I tried changing the permissions by right click and properties but it didn't help
Any help on how to do it through terminal would be appreciated
I have added this image for reference for better understanding of what's going on
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because it tries to change ownership of those respective files. It has nothing to do with permissions on the current directory.

Run the command as a root or use `sudo`.

You can change ownership after it gets extracted if you so desire using `chown -R <username>:<group> <path>` again as a root or using `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I will accept your answer after 5 minutes.
Wasted over 2 hours trying to figure this out

Comment: Tries to change the ownership of files, period. You can't give away files without being root (having the appropriate privilege), regardless of what the new owner would be.

Comment: Correct. Edited.